# trying to make a setup for using google's speech to text api using cpp

Tags: c++, freeswitch, google-cloud-speech

Hi from github I have cloned this module https://github.com/davehorton/drachtio-freeswitch-modules/tree/master/modules/mod_google_transcribe
Module created with ansible script is loading but I don't want to use that ansible script

So, by checking some documents installed grpc ,protobuf and googleapis packages.
I am able to make the module but it is not loading in the fs_console

021-01-08 12:55:44.823176 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1785 Error Loading module /usr/local/freeswitch/mod/mod_google_transcribe.so**/usr/local/freeswitch/mod/mod_google_transcribe.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN6google5cloud6speech2v16Speech4StubE**
getting this error

can anyone please help me

Comment: You don't provide any information about your code and the way you build your program. It's really hard to tell you anythig... Edit you post and give us more details :)

Comment: see I just need to make a setup for using google speech API with cpp and my operating system is linux  and about the code it is in the link provided above also I build grpc protobuf and googleapis packages ...

Comment: Were you able to solve it? If so, could you please help with gettiing the audio data out from freeswitch in real time using media_bug?

Comment: u can create a audio file of the speech coming in as by using record_session from dialplan or from the module